# How do I take null spaces out of an array?

Tags: java

I have to make a program that takes duplicate characters from an input array and prints out a new array with all unique characters.

It all works. Except when characters are taken out, it leaves an empty box at the end of that new array.

```
public class Deleter {

public static void main (String[] args){
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    char[] initialInputArray = new char[15];

    System.out.println("How many characters do you wish to enter?");

    int size = keyboard.nextInt();

    while ( size > initialInputArray.length ) {
        System.out.println("Error. Enter smaller number.");
        size = keyboard.nextInt();
    }
    if( initialInputArray.length <= 15) {           
        for ( int counter = 0; counter < size; counter++ ){             
            initialInputArray[counter] = keyboard.next().charAt(0);         
        }
        {

        }
    }

    deleteRepeats(initialInputArray, size); 
    //Comeback to print out array
    {
        for ( int helloWorld = 0 ; helloWorld < size ; helloWorld ++)
            System.out.print(  initialInputArray[helloWorld] );
    }
}



//"deleteReapets" method begins, looking for repeated user inputs
public static char[] deleteRepeats (char[] methodArray, int sizeTwo) {

    if (sizeTwo == 0)
        return methodArray;

    if (sizeTwo == 1)
        return methodArray;

    int uniqueCharacter = 1; 
    //Start at the second entered character.

    for (int x = 1; x < sizeTwo; ++x) { 
        int y;

        for (y = 0; y < uniqueCharacter; ++y) {
            if (methodArray[x] == methodArray[y]) break; // break if we find duplicate.
        }


        if (y == uniqueCharacter) {
            methodArray[uniqueCharacter] = methodArray[x]; // add
            ++uniqueCharacter; // increment uniqueCharacter...[0,uniqueCharacter) is still "unique char list"

        }
    }
    while ( uniqueCharacter < sizeTwo ) {
        methodArray[uniqueCharacter] = 0;
        uniqueCharacter++;

    }

            return methodArray;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

That empty box is the null characters that you added at the end of the array. You are printing them because you are not adjusting `size` according to the number of *unique* characters (which can be less than the input size). Since you aren't creating a new array, you don't need to return a `char []` from `deleteRepeats`. Instead, you can return the number of unique characters. That way, the calling program knows how many to print.

If your assignment requires that `deleteRepeats` return a `char[]`, then you should allocate a new array that has a length exactly equal to `uniqueCharacter`, copy the unique characters to it, and return that. The calling program can just print that new (and shorter) array, rather than printing the first `size` elements of the input.

Comment: I think I see what you're saying.

Comment: @user1292548 - First, I would change the declaration of `deleteRepeats` to return an `int` instead of a `char[]`. Then, I would eliminate the `while` loop at the end and just return `uniqueCharacters`. Then, in the calling program I would capture the return value and store it in `size`. Your program should then work the way you want.

Comment: How would I go about, "capture the return value and store it in size."? ...This seems like stupid question, now that I think about it.

Comment: Just: `size = deleteRepeats();`

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest way would be to make a new array to the size of your array of chars and then copy all of the chars into that.  The problem with arrays is that once they have been initialized they can't be re sized.  If your are familiar with arrayLists I would recommend using them. But if not try something like this...

```
int count = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < initialInputArray.size; i++){
        count++;
}

char[] newArray = new char[count];


for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
        newArray[i] = initialInputArray[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a [HashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) to remove duplicates and wrapping your char to [Character](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html). Something like this:

```
public static Character[] deleteRepeats (char[] methodArray){
    HashSet<Character> set = new HashSet<Character>();

    for(int index = 0; index < methodArray.length; index++){
        set.add(methodArray[index]);
    }

    return set.toArray(new Character[set.size()]);
}
```

So in your main method, what you would do is something like this:

```
Character[] charArray = deleteRepeats(methodArray);
for(int index = 0; index < charArray.length; index++){
    System.out.println(charArray[index]);
}
```

Comment: I haven't learned that yet. And I don't think my teacher would want me to submit something he hasn't gone over. Thanks though!

Comment: Ohh I didn't see the homework tag! Sorry :(, but I think you can keep this as a reference of using Set to remove duplicates :)